# how to switch ipython shell from version 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, ipython

I am new to python / coding and just recently started using ipython shell. However, it is automatically defaulted to python 2.7 version and I want to switch it to 3.6. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. I am using MacBook Air. Below is what it looks like when I launch python shell. And I have both Python versions installed.

```
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:10:39) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra   
details.
```

Comment: You should check out pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

Install ipython with pip3, not pip. It might be required to uninstall the existing version of ipython first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `which python` returns the python 3 binary. If it doesn't, you'll need to find the binary and add it to your `$PATH` in front of the python 2 binary

Comment: how do I find the binary?

Comment: Good question. How did you install python 3 in the first place? Try running `which python3`